# how do i insert spaces into a string using the range function?

Tags: python

If I have a string, for example  which reads: 'Hello how are you today Joe' How am I able to insert spaces into it at regular intervals? So for example I want to insert spaces into it using the range function in these steps: range(0,27,2). So it will look like this:

```
"He ll o  ho w  ar e  yo u  to da y  Jo e"
```

It now has a space at every 2nd index going up to it's end. How do I do this does anyone know? thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing "Hello" -> "Helo" is a typo and not part of the desired result?

Answer (score 20):

The most straight-forward approach for this particular case is

```
s = 'Hello how are you today Joe'
s = " ".join(s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2))
```

This splits the string into chunks of two characters each first, and then joins these chunks with spaces.

Comment: ...I'm in awe... edit: this isn't doing a check to see if the current character is a space though; the resulting string could end up with double spaces if the current character is already a space.

Comment: The OP has double spaces in their example, they just weren't visible because of the (lack of) formatting.

Comment: @Sven Marnach, What if I don't want double space? I am just curious. I think your solution for his question is great.

Comment: (I bet that there is a more elegant solution but)

`>>> s = " ".join(s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)).replace('  ', ' ')


    >>> s
'He ll o ho w ar e yo u to da y Jo e`

Comment: You can do: `s = ' '.join(' '.join(s[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(s), 2)).split())`

Comment: I like this answer although the `i+2` is hard coded in although I'm not sure if the OP minds.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to do it

```
>>> ''.join(e if (i+1)%2 else e+" " for (i,e) in enumerate(list(s)))
'He ll o  ho w  ar e  yo u  to da y  Jo e'
```

Answer (score 0):

This does everything!

```py
>>> def insert_spaces(text, s_range):
        return ' '.join(text[start:end] for start, end in 
                        zip([0] + s_range, s_range + [len(text)])).strip()
```

The question example:

```
>>> insert_spaces('Hello how are you today Joe', range(0, 27, 2))
'He ll o  ho w  ar e  yo u  to da y  Jo e'
```

Other examples with different `starts`, `steps` and `stops`:

```
>>> insert_spaces('Hello how are you today Joe', range(5, 20, 4))
'Hello  how  are  you  today Joe'
>>> insert_spaces('Hello how are you today Joe', range(0, 27))
'H e l l o   h o w   a r e   y o u   t o d a y   J o e'
>>> insert_spaces('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', range(0, 16, 5))
'abcde fghij klmno pqrstuvwxyz'
```