# How do I insert a space after a certain amount of characters in a string using python?

Tags: python, string

I need to insert a space after a certain amount of characters in a string. The text is a sentence with no spaces and it needs to be split with spaces after every n characters.

so it should be something like this.

```
thisisarandomsentence
```

and i want it to return as :

```
this isar ando msen tenc e
```

the function that I have is:

```
def encrypt(string, length):
```

is there anyway to do this on python?

Comment: Someone asked a question almost exactly like this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055631/how-do-i-insert-spaces-into-a-string-using-the-range-function/10055656#10055656

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055631/how-do-i-insert-spaces-into-a-string-using-the-range-function

Comment: Also this is kinda similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10061008/generating-all-n-tuples-from-a-string/10061368

Comment: I guess this question does have a difference, i'm not sure whether it is significant enough.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
def encrypt(string, length):
    return ' '.join(string[i:i+length] for i in range(0,len(string),length))
```

`encrypt('thisisarandomsentence',4)` gives

```
'this isar ando msen tenc e'
```

Comment: To be compatible with python 3 replace xrange by range

Answer (score 4):

```
import re
(' ').join(re.findall('.{1,4}','thisisarandomsentence'))
```

'this isar ando msen tenc e'

Answer (score 2):

Using [`itertools` grouper recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
        "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
        # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
        args = [iter(iterable)] * n
        return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

>>> text = 'thisisarandomsentence'
>>> block = 4
>>> ' '.join(''.join(g) for g in grouper(block, text, ''))
'this isar ando msen tenc e'
```

Comment: thankyou :) also worked!! been searching for this for the last 6 hours!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html) library (it comes included in python3):

```
import textwrap
def encrypt(string, length):
      a=textwrap.wrap(string,length)
      return a
```