# Convert sequences in codons

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I'm a noob and wonder what is the most efficient way to convert a DNA sequence `ATGGTGCCCCAG` etc into codons: `ATG GTG CCC CAG`. In essence, I'd like to print a file containing the sequence with a space between each codon.  The input file contains thousands of open reading frame sequences (i.e. no `UTR`).

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070434/how-do-i-insert-a-space-after-a-certain-amount-of-characters-in-a-string-using-p)

You're looking for something like this -

```
def splitCode(DNA):
    return ' '.join(DNA[i:i+3] for i in xrange(0,len(DNA),3))
```

Comment: Please don't provide answers for zero-effort questions.